# How do I declare a variable in the global scope for one command, and use in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

here is my code first of all:

```
if (command === "detain") {
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let det = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    detainer = message.member;
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Detained");
    var a = function none() {
        if (!member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Court")) {
            message.members.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Officer")).catch(console.error);
            member.removeRole(role).catch(console.error);
            det.setDescription("${message.author}, you have been impeached because no judges approved this detainment in the 5 minutes.");
        }
    };
    if (args.length < 2) {
        det.setDescription("Please add the reason this user has been detained.");
    } else {
        if (!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Officer") && !message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Chief of Police")) {
            det.setDescription("You must be an officer to use this command.");
        } else {
            det.setDescription(message.member + ", I have detained " + member + ". A judge must **!!approve** this detain within **5 minutes** or you will be IMPEACHED!");
            member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
            setTimeout(a, 300000);
        }
    }
    message.channel.send(det);
}
if (command === "approve") {
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let detained = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Detained");
    const approve = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Judge") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Chief Justice")) {
        if (member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Detained")) {
            member.removeRole(detained).catch(console.error);
            member.addRole(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Court"));
            approve.setDescription("${message.author}, " + member + " has been PUT IN COURT.");
            let roleName = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Judge");
            let membersWithJudge = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
                return member.roles.find("name", roleName);
            }).map(member => {
                return member.user.username;
            });
            var membersWithActualJudge = membersWithJudge.filter(e => e !== message.member);
            var judgeNum = (Math.random() * ((membersWithActualJudge.length) - 1) + 1)-1;
            var judgeToUse = membersWithActualJudge[judgeNum];
            var cj = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Chief Justice");
            var cp = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Chief of Police");
            message.guild.createChannel(detainer + "-vs-" + member, {
                type: 'text',
                permissionOverwrites: [{
                        id: 644313191962247178,
                        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: detainer.id,
                        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: cj.id,
                        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: cp.id,
                        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    },
                ],
            });
            let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "Court" && c.type == "category"),
                channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == (detainer + "-vs-" + member));
            if (category && channel) {
                channel.setParent(category.id);
                const sendThing = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("Court case: " + detainer + " vs. " + member + ". \n" + judgeToUse + " will be looking over this case.");
                sendThing.setDescription(judgeToUse + ", remember to read the laws, rights, and interpretations before delivering your verdict.");
                sendThing.addField("And always remember, feel free to ping [CENSORED], the President, or VP to get any help needed.");
                channel.send(sendThing);
                approve.setDescriiption("Approved successfully.");
            }
        } else {
            approve.setDescription("This user is not detained.");
        }
    } else {
        approve.setDescription("You must be a Judge to use this command.");
    }
    message.channel.send(approve);

}
```

So basically, I want a detain command and an approve command. Someone detains a user where they are muted, and someone else approves it. It then should create a brand new channel and sned something there. The problem here is 1. I can't get the @everyone role ID to work, 2. I can't store the detainer in global scope, and 3. ${message.author} wont work.

I don't really have much else, but thanks in advance

Comment: Where does `command` come from? Is this inside of some function? Please post the whole code.

Comment: hi d. you should simplify your code to the minimum that need to ask the question. it will bring you much more response . because read code take time

Comment: 1. this is discord.js

Comment: 2. this is as simple as i cang et it